# Is it possible to define variables in a task for a role?

Tags: ansible

I need to include a role in my own role, which relies on variables being set. Can I include them in a task and will they be applied to that included role?

Something like this:

```
- name: Configure firewall ports
  include_role:
    name: ipr-cnrs.nftables
  vars:
    - nft_define:
        input tcp accepted:
          name: in_tcp_accept
          value: '{ 22, 23 }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"Can I include the variables in a task and will they be applied to that included role?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. Correct syntax is

```yaml
- name: Configure firewall ports
  include_role:
    name: ipr_cnrs_nftables
  vars:
    nft_define:
      input tcp accepted:
        name: in_tcp_accept
        value: '{ 22, 23 }'
```

For example, the task

```yaml
shell> cat roles/ipr_cnrs_nftables/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: nft_define
```

gives

```
    "nft_define": {
        "input tcp accepted": null,
        "name": "in_tcp_accept",
        "value": "{ 22, 23 }"
    }
```

---

Notes:

- Quoting from [Role Names](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/creating_role.html#role-names)

> *"Role names are limited to lowercase word characters (i.e., a-z, 0-9) and ‘_’. No special characters are allowed, including ‘.’, ‘-‘, and space. During import, any ‘.’ and ‘-‘ characters contained in the repository name or role_name will be replaced with ‘_’."*

- The attribute value shall be a list of ports. It's a string in the example. Change it

```yaml
    value: [22, 23 ]
```

- In a playbook, the variable will be available when the flow-control reaches the `include` statement. See [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a variable with `include_role` as shown below according to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html):

```
- name: Pass variables to role
  include_role:
    name: myrole
  vars:
    rolevar1: value from task
```

So your example above can use `vars` with `include_role`.